# Is domConstruct in dojo an abstract class

Tags: java, class, dom, dojo

I have this really silly doubt.In the below code I have created an object for the container class and called the method getAllNodes() using that.So in the same way I tried to create an obj for domConstruct in the commented lines.But I'm getting "domConstruct is not a constructor" error.I've gone through the dom-construct.js file,where there is no constructor.Can someone also explain the class structure in dojo and provide resource for the same

```
  <body>
  <div id="cont">
    <p id="nodeone">one</p>
    <p id="nodetwo">two</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/dom","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/on","dojo/mouse","dojo/dnd/Container","dojo/domReady!"],function(dom,domConstruct){

      domConstruct.create("p",{innerHTML : "1.5"},"nodeone","after");

      //var obj = new domConstruct('nodeone');
      //obj.create("p",{innerHTML : "1.5"},"nodeone","after");

      var contObj = new Container("cont");
      cont.getAllNodes();

    }


);
  </script> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dojo/dom-construct`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html)  is a simple module that defines a dom utility function , so you access those directly by domConstruct callback reference without making instantiation .

Why ?

Already said that's a module (define). also, in dojo you have to use [`dojo/_base/declare`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html) in order to create a class , in order that your module will inherit the constructor method . so here  the `dojo/dom-construct` is a simple module , and does not use the declare module

You should use every [`dojo/dom-construct`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html) function directly without instantiation .